# Do collaborators have commit access on GitHub?

Tags: git, github

One thing I noticed: Using the GitHub UI, I added a collaborator to a repository. I saw that they committed changes without any authority / approval from me. It was a private repository.

With private repositories, how do I give someone read access versus write access?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> With private repositories, how do I give someone read access versus write access?

This kind of permission is not available for simple accounts. When you add an user as a collaborator, he gains read/write permissions.

The story changes if you own an [Organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations). Organizations contains teams and each team can have different level of access, including read-only.
You can assign users to a specific read-only group, and they will only have pull access to the repositories.

Comment: @Simone: Does it also mean that the collaborators can "accept" their own pull requests on behalf of the repo owner? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8502540/583539

Answer (score 8):

Private repositories in an ordinary user account are an all-or-nothing deal: either someone has full read/write access (i.e., they're a *collaborator*) or they have no access. However, if you set up an [organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations), create the repo under the aegis of the organization, and then add the collaborator, you have much more fine-grained control (including giving read-only access to a private repo).

Comment: Or you make your repository public, then everyone (who is not a collaborator) has read-only access.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: True, but...not really a good option if you need to keep the repo private.